# android video playback using mediaCodec in native code

Tags: android, media

I am trying to play a video in android native code using new API mediacodec. I dont want to go mediaPlayer way due to unavoidable reasons. can anybody share some code snippet as to how to go about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried? Share the code that you tried and issues that you face.

Answer (score 3):

Your original question is too generic. And to be honest, create a new media player in native code is a huge task for your own.

If you are only seeking for some media player solution which has better supporting for variety of formats/codecs like VLC player, you can either try VLC lib which is open source but still in beta release. I have tried VLC, but it really has some crash issues or ANR issues, which is inside the whole framework.

Or you can try with Vitamio SDK which is a library without souce code.  Check it out at this link: https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle Below is the feature list of it:

I have tried this solution, it is very stable, also some minor issue on 4.3, but still acceptable. So I am not posting any spam here, just copying from the official document:

Vitamio is an open multimedia framework or library for Android and iOS, with full and real hardware accelerated decoder and renderer. It's the simple, clean and powerful API of Vitamio that makes it famous and popular in multimedia apps development for Android and iOS.
According to the developers' feedback, Vitamio has been used by more than 1000 apps and 100 million users around the world.

Vitamio can play 720p/1080p HD mp4,mkv,m4v,mov,flv,avi,rmvb,rm,ts,tp and many other video formats in Android and iOS. Almost all popular streaming protocols are supported by Vitamio, including HLS(m3u8), MMS, RTSP, RTMP, and HTTP.

**Network Protocols**

The following streaming protocols are supported for audio and video playback:

MMS
RTSP (RTP, SDP), RTMP
HTTP progressive streaming
HLS - HTTP live streaming (M3U8)
And yes, Vitamio can handle on demand and live videos in all above protocols.

**Media formats**

Vitamio used FFmpeg as the demuxers and main decoders, many audio and video codecs are packed into Vitamio beside the default media format built in Android platform, some of them are listed below.

DivX/Xvid
WMV
FLV
TS/TP
RMVB
MKV
MOV
M4V
AVI
MP4
3GP

**Subtitles**

Vitamio support the display of many external and embedded subtitle formats.

SubRip(.srt)
Sub Station Alpha(.ssa) / Advanced Sub Station Alpha(.ass)
SAMI(.smi/.sami)
MicroDVD(.sub/.txt)
SubViewer2.0(.sub)
MPL2(.mpl/.txt)
Matroska (.mkv) Subtitle Track
More features

**More wonderful features**

Support wide range screens from small phone to large tablet
Multiple audio tracks support
Mutitiple subtitles support, including external and embedded ones
Processor optimization for many platforms
Buffering when streaming
Adjustable aspect ratio
Automatically text encoding detection

Comment: Vitamio play youtube video. I tried it but not supported..."http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbdQcNBrK8c" url

Comment: i was try to play audio stream by this sdk. but i can't.my application throw android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: io.vov.vitamio error. i add vitamio jar file in libs folder.please post some code how i can play media player.